# Getting RVM to work with Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: ruby, bash, jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration

So I'm trying to setup a Jenkins declarative Pipeline to run an Xcode build job. I want to use xcpretty Ruby gem but will also need several other Ruby gems later for other jobs.

```
stage('Pre-Build')
{
    steps
    {
        echo "Executing Pre-Build steps ..."
        sh(returnStdout: true, script: "#!/bin/bash -xle && source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm && rvm use 2.3.1 && cd ${WORKSPACE}/${env.PROJECT_PATH} && gem install xcpretty && set -o pipefail && xcpretty")
    }
}
```

First off all, I get no echo for the sh in Pre-Build stage whatsoever. Neither `returnStdout: true` nor the hashbang seem to have any effect on getting any log output from the shell invocation.

That leaves me blind on what's going on here. When running the job, the Pre-Build stage passes and then it fails at my actual build stage when I want to use xcpretty.

Here's the log output from the Pre-Build stage:

```
Executing Pre-Build steps ...
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[job] Running shell script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build)
[Pipeline] echo
```

If I run it in the bash manually, no problem! On Jenkins it seems that something isn't working with RVM but I'm tapping in the dark while trying to fix this for days and it drives me insane.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Use docker instead for this.

Comment: How so? Care to elaborate a bit more? (Sorry, I'm new to Docker).

Comment: Build a Docker image that has all of the gems inside and then spin it up using the Jenkins Docker Pipeline plugin.

Comment: Ok but will that work without problem with any dependencies outside the Docker image, e.g Xcode tools?

Comment: I just checked  the `xcpretty` github page and it doesn't depend on Xcode tools; it just manipulates their stdout.

Answer (score 3):

Michał Knapik has a blog post covering one hand-rolled solution which defines a groovy wrapper which replicates `rvm use` semantics

See:

https://blog.knapik.me/how-to-use-rvm-with-jenkins-pipeline/

```
node {
    withRvm('ruby-2.3.1') {
        sh 'ruby --version'
        sh 'gem install rake'
    }
}
```

I don't want to copy any more than this example - its his code.

Note the caveats on specifying the version